# How to replace mth to nth occurance of a string in bash using sed?

Tags: sed, text-processing

I have been looking for an easy way to mask(i.e replace with *) 1st to 3rd occurrence of a given pattern in each line **using *sed*.**

The format of input text is;

```
$ cat input
1234 4321 2356 7890
3456 4567 8765 0981
2345 2167 9876 1234
```

The required output;

```
**** **** **** 7890
**** **** **** 0981
**** **** **** 1234
```

After looking around I found the way of replacing *only n'th occurrence* of the specified pattern. Here how you replace the 2nd block of each line in given input.

```
$ cat input | sed  's/[0-9]\{4\}/****/2'
1234 **** 2356 7890
3456 **** 8765 0981
2345 **** 9876 1234
```

Also we can replace *all occurrences* of the given pattern *starting from* n'th occurrence. Here's how you do it.

```
$ cat input | sed  's/[0-9]\{4\}/****/2g'
1234 **** **** ****
3456 **** **** ****
2345 **** **** ****
```

P.S I would appreciate a *simple & stupid* solution. Not the solutions with *awk* or labels & loops in *sed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** IMHO if you ask me simple solution then I would go for `awk`. If your Input_file contains only 4 fields then simply do, simply assign the values to 3 fields.

```
awk '{$1=$2=$3="****"} 1'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With `sed`(this could be the way OP was trying to write). Using `sed`'s capability to use temp buffer to store matched regex and later replace it with `****`  while substitution.

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/**** **** **** \4/'  Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Use `rev` to print Input_file reverse then catch only first(which is actually last field in Input_file) and then print 3 times `****` and again print it reverse which will print it now in its actual form :)

```
rev Input_file | sed 's/\([^ ]*\).*/\1 **** **** **** ****/' | rev
```

***4th solution:*** More generic solution, where person can give range of field numbers from which field to which field person wants to change value to `****` then try following (`from` and `to` are the variables which could be set by person to change values according to field numbers).

```
awk -v from="1" -v to="3" '{for(i=from;i<=to;i++){$i="****"}} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the crisp answer !! awk really makes it super easy. But actually I am trying to figure out how to use the "find and replace" in sed. Also could you please tell why do we put that "1" at the last ? I checked that without that I'm not getting any output and why does any other integers instead of "1" work as well ?

Comment: @MridulGain, Hey Mridul, `awk` works on method of condition and then action. If a condition is  true then action will happen; so by mentioning `1` I am making condition TRUE and didn't mention any action so by default print of current line will happen, btw I added sed solutions too out of 4, 2 are sed. Please do lemme know in case you have any other queries :)

Answer (score 2):

"Simple" and "stupid" you ask. I'll leave you to decide how this is ;). GNU `sed` does support a pattern to start the replacement from `sed /../[n]g`, but does not allow a stop range. You can mention `2g`, to start replacement from 2nd occurrence but can't define a range, as 1st to 3rd occurrence.

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]\{4\}/****/; s/[0-9]\{4\}/****/; s/[0-9]\{4\}/****/' file
```

But disowning `awk` for a trivial substitution like this is *not* a good idea. It is way more useful and simple to use than you think.

Answer (score 2):

With your simple input example:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4} ){3}/**** **** **** /' input
```

A more complicated solution is given in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155810/57293.

Another simple solution (when you know the nr of patterns in the line) is

```
rev input | sed -r 's/[0-9]{4}/****/g2' | rev
```